# ZedGraph: Custom Labels on XAxis.DateAsOrdinal

Tags: c#, zedgraph

I am confounded by this problem:  I have a WinForm with ZedGraph object plotting a simple curve.  It has a custom text object "C" above each point.  When I change the XAxis.Type to DateAsOrdinal, the "C" text label disappears.  How can I get "C" with DateAsOrdinal to work?

The code is below for anyone to try:

```
    private void DrawChart( ZedGraphControl zGraph ) {
        GraphPane pane = zGraph.GraphPane;
        pane.Title.Text = "My Sample Test";
        pane.XAxis.Title.Text = "Date";
        pane.YAxis.Title.Text = "Price";

        // Uncomment below line: all "C" labels disappear!
        //pane.XAxis.Type = AxisType.DateAsOrdinal;

        double x, y;
        PointPairList points = new PointPairList();
        DateTime day = new DateTime( 2012, 1, 1 );

        for ( int i = 0 ; i < 36 ; i++ ) {
            x = day.ToOADate();
            y = 1.5 + Math.Sin( (double)i * 0.2 );
            points.Add( x, y );

            // this label disappears when XAxis.Type = DateAsOrdinal!
            TextObj text = new TextObj( "C", x, y + 0.1, CoordType.AxisXYScale, AlignH.Center, AlignV.Center );
            text.ZOrder = ZOrder.A_InFront;
            text.FontSpec.Border.IsVisible = false;
            pane.GraphObjList.Add( text );

            day = day.AddDays( 1 );   // goto next day (x-coord)
        }

        LineItem curve = pane.AddCurve( "Stock", points, Color.Black, SymbolType.None );

        zGraph.AxisChange();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

> new TextObj("C", i + 1, y + .....

Ordinal XAxis means as expression implies that x values will run 1, 2, 3...

Comment: Ok, this quick hack fixes the label problem.

It's still unintuitive 'coz just one statement earlier

Points.Add(x, y);

the x is not in the range { 1, 2, 3, ... }

I would expect Points and TextObj to perform consistently, but I guess this is one quirk in ZedGraph currently.

Comment: No hack nor quirk. You chose an ordinal axis, what's zedgraph supposed to do? Nobody's forcing you. ;) It still uses OADate x values for displaying scale labels, so it needs them.

Comment: With all due respect, I think ZedGraph's design can be improved: a Point and a TextObj are both objects on the same GraphPane. Given the same x and y, I would expect both Point(x,y) and TextObj(x,y) to be plotted to the same location. It is non-intuitive that I need to do Point(x=Date.ToOADate,y) and TextObj(x=i+1,y) to get them to the same horizontal position, especially when Date.ToOADate is not equal to i+1 in value.

Comment: If it's not immediately intuitive you assume it's a poor design rather than due to benefits you have not yet experienced, although you clearly have just started to use the library. That's a mistake on your part imo. Library is open source and can be improved, but this is not something I advice you to change, to put it very carefully. Don't expect it to be a 30-min plug-and-play control, but rather to be extremely customizable. You don't get lamb chops at the drive-in.